# Mat-accordion is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on an angular10 application, I am trying to use mat-accordion in my project, using modules per component(each and every component has it own module.ts file) below is my module file code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CaseCardComponent } from '../casecard/casecard.component';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';





 @NgModule({
      declarations: [CaseCardComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatCardModule
      ]
    })
    export class CasecardModule { }
```

then below is the line that throws an error "Mat-accordion is not a known element" (this is in the html file)

```
<mat-accordion>
    
</mat-accordion>
```

What is funny though, is the  tag from the MatCardModule seems to be working perfectly(used it as test just to see if perhaps that something wrong with the module itself), is the something I am doing wrong here

Note: Importing MatCardExpansion module as suggested by many others did not really help me

Comment: what is the line and what is the error?

Comment: @Felix I just updated my question and included the error as well as the line giving me gray hairs

Comment: Importing `MatExpansionModule` (and putting it in `imports`) allows me to use `mat-accordeon` without problems... so, it must be something outside the code you posted. did you install `@angular/cdk` (I assume you did - but that's the only thing coming to mind)

Answer (score 5):

Did you stop & restart your development server of angular? Sometimes adding modules (or doing `npm install`) while `ng serve` is active does not correctly update.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is something stupid, but in my case, I did everything I saw in SO and nothing worked until I put the MatExpansionModule before the other Mat*Modules I have...