# VS Code doesn't understand my Angular templates

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I don't know why, but this is what VS Code gives me

[image]

My code compiles without any issues, so it must be VS Code related. Something in this component seems the mess things up in VS Code, because other components have no issues whatsoever. Also, the message suggests to use CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA, which I have defined in my module file.

The structure of my Angular app is very basic, one module-file for everything, but the project is part of a nx monorepo. I have the Angular Language Service plugin installed, so I don't know what might be the reason of those errors I see in VS Code.

Comment: Did you add the component in the module as suggested by the error message? Restarting VS Code and ng serve also often helps (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65178231/2742007)

Comment: I think adding `CdkAccordionModule` is all you need to do. I also removed my node_modules and reinstalled everything, restarted vscode, but it all comes back

Comment: Have you found any solution? Suddenly I've faced with the same problem, sources don't have any errors, but VSCode fails to recognize components and directives. It works also on top of NX.

Comment: No not yet. As soon as I have found a solution I'll post it here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that this is a problem of the Angular Language Service extension. Now, if you go into `settings` and uncheck the following config option of that extension

[image]

it seems to work again

My answer was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393646/angular-language-service-not-working-in-vscode) post

Answer (score 0):

I find the example on https://material.angular.io/cdk/accordion/examples confusing, as it creates a new component but uses the base `cdk-accordion` and `cdk-accordion-item`.

From your screenshot it looks like you're also using the base components.

Without more details on your code, we can only blindly guess about your issue. I have created a simple demo that work on Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bgkn9s?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion%2Faccordion.component.ts

Mind following

- `npm install @angular/cdk`
- app.modules.ts: imports, declarations

as in

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {CdkAccordionModule} from '@angular/cdk/accordion';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { AccordionComponent } from './accordion/accordion.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, CdkAccordionModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, AccordionComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I must say that I have done all this. I realise that my post doesn't provide enough information, but it isn't easy to do so in this case. I can't post my whole monorepo :) Thanks for the help!